# Pull data from node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on an node application where I've to fetch data from a particular URI running on node.
I've to continuously listen to the remote URI and fetch data if there are any changes.
I'm absolutely new to node.js and not sure how to proceed.
I can think this in terms of python, which is straight forward.

```
var http = require('http');

var request = http.request({
  port: 8888,
  host: 'localhost',
  method: 'GET'
});
request.on('response', function (res) {
  res.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
request.end();
```

My node application should run like a background process which always listens to the particular URI and update the JSON response in local when there is change detected.

Can someone help me on this.
Will socket.io help here?

Comment: You cannot use sockets to connect to a server, it's that server that you are listening to that requires to have sockets so you can connect to it. Can you share some code with what you tried so far?

Comment: @RocoCTZ added code

Comment: Does the remote source send any notifications? How do you know when the data is changed?

Comment: No, I've to keep listening for regular intervals of time and update my location json accordingly

Comment: Ok, then what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest option would be to use setInterval(myFunction, timeInMs) to run your request on an interval but it's not exactly robust. It's been too long since I've worked with socket.io but I think the web server would have to be set up to use WebSockets but if you can change the server then that's an option. I think what you want to do is find a good long-polling library but I don't know of one off the top of my head.